# Pausing/Stopping Gif animation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am using gif animation in WPF application, an external dll *WpfAnimatedGif.dll* is used for showing the animation. The animation is working properly, but I am unable to pause/stop it on a certain event let say button click, how can I do it, kindly guide me, my xaml code is given below

```
<Image x:Name="scaner" Stretch="UniformToFill" gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="{StaticResource gifImage}"  >
```

Comment: As the animation is done by an external dll, you should ask your vendor. That's nothing that can be answered with standard WPF knowledge.

Comment: Great... and in the very same link you posted, did you read the section called **"Manual control of the animation"** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your documentation (which you should have read yourself) this will work:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var controller = ImageBehavior.GetAnimationController(this.scaner);

    controller.Pause();
}
```

Please note that working directly with button functions is not the prefered way in WPF, if you want to use the full power I suggest using MVVM and the command pattern instead.

Comment: thanx I am using MVVM, that was just for the sake of finding some solution

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, use reference

```
xamlAnimationWpf Nuget <br>
var controller = AnimationBehavior.GetAnimator(myGif); <br>
controller.Pause();<br>
```

For those who try another way